# Subtracting equations from each other?

Tags: algebra

I have two equations

```
eqhy

-2 x + f[x, y[x]] - x^2 y[x]^3 == hy[y[x]]

eqfhx
-2 E^(4 y[x]) + f[x, y[x]] - x^2 y[x]^3 == hx[x]
```

I would like to subtract these equations from one another, like this

```
solu12 = eqhy - eqfhx
```

which currently yields

```
-(-2 E^(4 y[x]) + f[x, y[x]] - x^2 y[x]^3 == hx[x]) + (-2 x + 
f[x, y[x]] - x^2 y[x]^3 == hy[y[x]])
```

I would like it to yield the actual remaining terms

How do I do this in mathematica?

Comment: `Inner[Subtract, eqhy, eqfhx, Equal]`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

An easy way to munge equations is to convert them to lists and then convert them back to equations when you are done munging. In your case, like so:

```
eq1 = -2 x + f[x, y[x]] - x^2 y[x]^3 == hy[y[x]]; 
eq2 = -2 E^(4 y[x]) + f[x, y[x]] - x^2 y[x]^3 == hx[x];
w1 = List @@ eq1;
w2 = List @@ eq2;
w3 = w1 - w2;
eq3 = Equal @@ w3
```

> `2 E^(4 y[x]) - 2 x == -hx[x] + hy[y[x]]`

Answer (score 7):

I'm going to guess that your actual goal here is to eliminate one of the terms shared by the two equations. In that case, you could also use [`Eliminate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Eliminate.html):

```
Eliminate[{eqfhx,eqhy},f[x,y[x]]]
```

> $\text{hy}(y(x))-2 e^{4 y(x)}+2 x=\text{hx}(x)$

This doesn't do the subtraction exactly the way you asked for, but usually the goal of such a subtraction is to eliminate something. And that's why this may be the thing you actually need. It has the advantage that it will figure out *how* to do the subtraction all by itself.

Answer (score 5):

You could use [`Inner`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inner.html), which is similar to `Dot` operation on matrices (but with operation of your choice not `Times` and `Plus`).

In the following code, the first element (LHS) of the first argument (`eqhy`) is subtracted by the first element (LHS) of the second argument (`eqfhx`), and second element (RHS) of the first argument (`eqhy`) is subtracted by the second element (RHS) of the second argument (`eqfhx`):

```
eqhy = -2 x + f[x, y[x]] - x^2 y[x]^3 == hy[y[x]];
eqfhx = -2 E^(4 y[x]) + f[x, y[x]] - x^2 y[x]^3 == hx[x];
Inner[Subtract, eqhy, eqfhx, Equal]
```

> `2 E^(4 y[x]) - 2 x == -hx[x] + hy[y[x]]`

Answer (score 5):

This seemed merely cute at first, but, after thinking about it, it actually can be useful:

```
eqhy - eqfhx /. Equal -> List /. List -> Equal  (* remember that Plus threads over List *) 
(*  2 E^(4 y[x]) - 2 x == -hx[x] + hy[y[x]]  *)
```

We can add multiples of equations this way, too:

```
(x + 2 y == 3) - 2 (2 x + y == 4) /. Equal -> List /. List -> Equal
Simplify[%]
(*
  x + 2 y - 2 (2 x + y) == -5
  3 x == 5
*)
```

Likewise, we can take the dot product of a system of equations with a vector of coefficients:

```
{1, -2, 1}.{2 x + 3 y - z == 3, x + y + 2 z == 4, 2 x - y + 2 z == 4} /.
   Equal -> List /. List -> Equal // Expand
(*  2 x - 3 z == -1  *)
```

Thinking about it further, the trick effectively does the same computational steps as m_goldberg's answer, only without needed extra variables.