# How to subtract these two equations?

Tags: replacement, expression-manipulation

There are two equations:

```
eq1 = x1^2/a^2 + y1^2/b^2 == 1;
eq2 = x2^2/a^2 + y2^2/b^2 == 1;
```

How to get this result by subtracting two equations?

the result

```
((x1 - x2) (x1 + x2))/a^2 + ((y1 - y2) (y1 + y2))/b^2 == 0
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> subtracting two equations?

You can use [SubtractSides](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SubtractSides.html) which is designed for this sort of operation.

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
eq1 = x1^2/a^2 + y1^2/b^2 == 1
eq2 = x2^2/a^2 + y2^2/b^2 == 1
SubtractSides[eq1, eq2]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

To simplify it more

```
SubtractSides[eq1, eq2] // Simplify
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Without using this command, there are other ways to do this. See [Subtracting equations from each other?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/125609/subtracting-equations-from-each-other)  for more options.

Answer (score 4):

```
(eq1 - eq2 /. Equal -> List // Equal @@ # & // 
   Collect[#, {a, b}] &) /. (a_^2 - b_^2) :> (a + b) (a - b)
```

$$\frac{(\text{x1}-\text{x2}) (\text{x1}+\text{x2})}{a^2}+\frac{(\text{y1}-\text{y2}) (\text{y1}+\text{y2})}{b^2}$$

Comment: Could you have a look at my SDE question: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/276606/numerically-solving-a-system-of-sdes-with-levy-noise?noredirect=1#comment697578_276606. Thank you!

Comment: @Math, I don't have enough expertise in that area. The most qualified participants have already looked at it. If you have another question, it is best to start a fresh post. Thanks.

Comment: No problem, Thank you anyway :)

Answer (score 3):

Try also this:

```
eq1 = x1^2/a^2 + y1^2/b^2 == 1;
eq2 = x2^2/a^2 + y2^2/b^2 == 1;



  expr=Equal @@ MapThread[Subtract, {List @@ eq1, List @@ eq2}] // Simplify

(*  (x1^2 - x2^2)/a^2 + (y1^2 - y2^2)/b^2 == 0  *)
```

If you need them factorized:

```
MapAt[Factor, expr, {{1, 1}, {1, 2}}]

(*  ((x1 - x2) (x1 + x2))/a^2 + ((y1 - y2) (y1 + y2))/b^2 == 0  *)
```

Have fun!

Answer (score 3):

Another way to do this is as follows:

```
FullSimplify[Thread[#[[1]] == #[[2]]] &@(#[[1]] - #[[2]] & /@ 
Transpose[Level[#, {1}] & /@ {eq1, eq2}])]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
eq1 = x1^2/a^2 + y1^2/b^2 == 1;
eq2 = x2^2/a^2 + y2^2/b^2 == 1;
```

Original way

```
eq1 - eq2 // Thread[#, Equals] & // Simplify
(* (x1^2-x2^2)/a^2+(y1^2-y2^2)/b^2==0 *)
```

If you use EqualThread found at https://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/4491, then it will be seamless.

```
eq1 - eq2//Simplify
```

to get the same answer.