# How to perform item shifting deformation?

Tags: list-manipulation, equation-solving, replacement, pattern-matching

[How to subtract the two equations. That is, the left subtraction of the two equations is equal to the right subtraction of the equation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/279191/how-to-subtract-the-two-equations-that-is-the-left-subtraction-of-the-two-equa)

Continue to the previous question, how to perform the term shift deformation?

```
eq1 = x1^2/a^2 + y1^2/b^2 == 1;
eq2 = x2^2/a^2 + y2^2/b^2 == 1;
SubtractSides[eq1, eq2] // FullSimplify
```

get the result:

```
((x1 - x2) (x1 + x2))/a^2 + ((y1 - y2) (y1 + y2))/b^2 == 0
```

The problem now is how to shift the above results to get this result:

```
((y1 - y2) (y1 + y2))/((x1 - x2) (x1 + x2)) == - b^2/a^2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is your equation:

```
eqA = ((x1 - x2) (x1 + x2))/a^2 + ((y1 - y2) (y1 + y2))/b^2 == 0;
```

Try the following:

```
eqB = eqA /. b -> Sqrt[z]*a // Simplify[#, {a > 0, z > 0}] &

(*  y1^2 + x1^2 z == y2^2 + x2^2 z  *)

Equal @@ Solve[eqB, z][[1, 1]] /. z -> b^2/a^2

(*  b^2/a^2 == (-y1^2 + y2^2)/(x1^2 - x2^2)  *)
```

Have fun!

Answer (score 3):

```
eq1 = x1^2/a^2 + y1^2/b^2 == 1;
eq2 = x2^2/a^2 + y2^2/b^2 == 1;
(SubtractSides[eq1, eq2] //
    Collect[#, {a, b}] &) /.
  (a_^2 - b_^2) :> (a + b) (a - b) /. {a_. b_ + c_. d_ == 0 -> 
   d/b == -(a/c)}
```

$$\frac{(\text{y1}-\text{y2}) (\text{y1}+\text{y2})}{(\text{x1}-\text{x2}) (\text{x1}+\text{x2})}=-\frac{b^2}{a^2}$$